# Related to Hartshorne Exercise 2.4.3, nothing to do with separatedness or properness.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $U = \text{Spec}\,A$ and $V = \text{Spec}\,B$ be open affines in a scheme $X$ (not necessarily separated). How do I show that for each $P \in U \cap V$ there is an open affine $W$ such that $P \in W$, $W \subseteq U \cap V$, and there are elements $f \in A$ and $g \in B$ such that $W$ equals $D(f)$ in $\text{Spec}\,A$ and $D(g)$ in $\text{Spec}\,B$?

Comment: See Section 5.3 of Vakil's notes for the argument. It's neat.

Answer (score 2):

Since $U \cap V$ is open in $U$, there exists $f_0 \in A$ such that $P \in D(f_0)$ and $D(f_0) \subseteq U \cap V$. Since $D(f_0)$ is open in $V$, there exists $g \in B$ such that $P \in D(g)$ and $D(g) \subseteq D(f_0)$. But now $g \in B = \Gamma(V, \mathcal{O}_X)$, so it restricts to an element of $\Gamma(D(f), \mathcal{O}_X) = A_f$. Thus $g = a/f_0^r$ for some $a \in A$ and $r \in \mathbb{N}$. Moreover, $D(g) = D(a) \cap D(f_0)$ since a point $P \in D(f_0)$ or $V$ lies in $D(g)$ if and only if the germ $g_P$ lies in the maximal ideal of the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{X, P}$. Let $f = af_0$. Then $D(f) = D(a) \cap D(f_0) = D(g)$, and we are done. (Thus $U \cap V$ is covered by **common** principal open subsets.)